# python gevent, why is monkey's patch_all and patch_thread Event kwarg default to False (and what does this do)

Tags: python, gevent

I can't find info about this in the docs, and I only thought to try setting it to `True` after looking at the source.  It seems setting this to `True` makes the `patch_thread` method which is called by `patch_all` execute this code eventually:

```
    if Event:
        from gevent.event import Event
        patch_item(threading, 'Event', Event)
```

This apparently patches the threading modules `Event` class with gevent's.

This seems to have fixed my original problem I had been having up to this point with DummyThreads living in memory forever (which eventually eats up all the system memory).

As I've been hitting my head off of this problem for a day now, I am super excited to just call setting `Event=True` on the patching method as the solution.  However, I feel there's probably a reason it was set to default to False.

Any one know what that reason might be?

Using python 2.7
gevent 1.1 (freshly minted!)

Cheers